# Example of excision in Hochschild homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

The excision theorem for Hochschild homology introduced by Wodzicki seems like a very powerful tool (as scision was hyper-useful in topology).

However, I cannot actually seem to think of a result where it yields interesting computations.

So my question is, can someone show me a case where the Wodzicki excision theorem actually helps compute the Hochschild homology of an algebra in a useful way?

Comment: The spelling is "Wodzicki."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in *Cyclic Homology* by Loday, theorem 1.4.14:

> **Theorem**: Let $I$ be a H-unital $k$-algebra. Then $M_r(I)$ (matrices of size $r$) is $H$-unital for all $r$ (including $r =
> > \infty$), and the maps (resp. induced by the trace and the inclusion):
>   $$\begin{align} \mathrm{tr}_* & : HH_*(M_r(I), M_r(M)) \to HH_*(I,M)
> \\ \mathrm{inc}_* & : HH_*(I, M) \to HH_*(M_r(I), M_r(M))
> \end{align}$$ are isomorphisms and inverse to each other.

This theorem is proven using excision (I am not courageous enough to copy the proof here). It's called *Morita invariance*. Excision is used to go from unital algebras (where you can prove Morita invariance "easily") to merely H-unital algebras.

---

Another example is Mayer-Vietoris (exercise E.1.4.5 in Loday's book): if $$\begin{array}{ccc} A &  \to & B \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ C & \to & D \end{array}$$ is a pullback square of unital $k$-algebras and $B \to D$ is surjective and $k$-split, then there is a long exact sequence:
$$\dots \to HH_n(A) \to HH_n(B) \oplus HH_n(C) \to HH_n(D) \to HH_{n-1}(A) \to \dots$$